# What is the default repositories on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit?

Tags: ppa, repository, software-sources

I followed some commands online to install skype but now my repository list is filled with stuff i dont want. How can i restore back the list in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit?

OS:Linux Ubuntu
OS Version:16.04 LTS
OS Architecture: 64-bit

[image: Repository List]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply uncheck or remove everything with `ppa.launchpad.net` in its name. All the standard repositories are configured in the <kbd>Ubuntu Software</kbd> tab and not in the <kbd>Other Software</kbd> tab where you are looking.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, don't forget to accept it by clicking the grey round tick symbol on the left of it. This will also mark your question as solved. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.